# Syfy show with an alien surgeon operating on a man who has memories of black holes

Tags: story-identification

A man was going under surgery to remove something from his brain; the surgeon was an alien who is very sensitive to bacteria and every time she was going to remove a piece it triggered a memory. He remembers something about black holes and starts speaking a different language.

Somebody walks in and breathes into the surgeon's mouth, killing her.

Comment: Please [edit] this question to divide it into sentences and paragraphs, also fixing capitalisation and punctuation. You should also add more detail, for which you can get some insight [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info). For instance, "a long time ago" is not useful in any way.

Answer (score 11):

**This is the Farscape episode [Die Me, Dichotomy](http://farscape.wikia.com/wiki/Die_Me,_Dichotomy).**

The man in question is the protagonist, John Crichton and the surgeon is the Diagnosan, [Tocot](http://farscape.wikia.com/wiki/Tocot).

Answer (score 9):

I'm pretty sure you're talking about an episode of [Farscape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farscape).

Did the surgeon look like this?:

[image]

The incident you're describing happened in the last episode of season 2/first of season 3.

- A man was going under surgery to remove something from his brain

  - The series' main character, John Crichton, has been implanted with a neural 'chip', which has expanded across his brain, and needs to have it removed.
- the surgeon was an alien who is very sensitive to bacteria

  - The surgeon is a [Diagnosan](http://farscape.wikia.com/wiki/Diagnosan), a species with excellent natural diagnostic abilities but extreme sensitivity to infections. They normally wear masks when out and about.
- every time she was going to remove a piece it triggered a memory and then he remembers something about black holes

  - Because the doctor is not familiar with humans, he needs to know what different parts of the brain are doing when he stimulates them.

Comment: It was wormholes.